# WiFi(n)-USB2 vs WiFi(n)-USB3 vs Powerline

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet, powerline-networking

In the process of upgrading/rebuilding the home PC, and most decent mobos have fancy Ethernet. My current setup uses a WiFi-USB2 adapter ([Asus N14](https://www.asus.com/Networking/USBN14/)), due to poor choices and GPON Internet (ISP-mandated router/AP is an 802.11n Huawei). With no line-of-sight signal I am getting 108-144 Mbps (Local)/4-6 Mbps (Internet) on a good day, with occasional lag (unclear if due to wireless interference or adapter/PC issues).
**The question**: would I be better of with a USB3-compatible WiFi-USB adapter if the router stays the same (n)? Would a Powerline LAN setup (assume AV2, current gen)  get me better speeds (assume the wiring is subpar)? Thanks

Comment: You can use your own router, connected to the ISP provided gateway (disable the wireless on the gateway), and connect to the faster wireless network provided your own router.  If you stay with 802.11n you will always be limited by 802.11, even if you connect to it with a 802.11ad device, you won't get faster then 802.11n speeds.  You have not been specific enough about the potential Powerline setup.  The first generation of Powerline wasn't very fast.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of that - unfortunately, my only spare router is 802.11n, and Internet speeds don't warrant an upgrade

Comment: Your current problem is your intranet speeds.  If you upgrade your intranet router, you will get the same bandwidth, as your internet bandwidth.  You currently have a huge bottleneck.

Comment: My internet is up to 10mbitps up/5 down, and I am usually getting half of that - is there really a bottleneck?

Comment: "With no line-of-sight signal I am getting 108-144mbps on a good day, with occasional lag (unclear if due to wireless interference or adapter/PC issues)." - You indicated as much.  You are at the lower spectrum of 802.11n currently.  What you gain by upgrading is the additional MMO streams.

Comment: clarified the speeds in the op

Comment: In my conversion, 8 Mbps is 18MBps, not what you stated.  Which again at the lower spectrum of 802.11n speeds due to the signal strength.  I can only assume mbps is Mbps instead of MBps since you would not complain if you were getting 108 MBps downloads